# What does the engine and char set means after the ()?

Tags: mysql

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `Database` ;
CREATE DATABASE `Database` ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Registration Form` ;
CREATE TABLE `Registration Form`
(
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `Username` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
    `Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
    `Display Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `Question` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `Answer` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `Title` varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
    `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `Date Of Birth` date NOT NULL ,
    `Gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
    `Address` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `Postal Code` int(11) NOT NULL ,
    `City / Town` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `Federal Territory / State` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `Citizenship` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `E-mail` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `Contact Number` int(20) NOT NULL ,
    `Registration Date` datetime NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

I'm just starting to work arounnd mysql and php ... so bear with me as im a newbie ...
What does ALL the code after the CREATE() mean ? Why is there a ENGINE and DEFAULT what do they do ? Is CHARSET same as collation , if yes why not put it inside the row instead ? Do you need to give a length/value for date and daetime ?

Comment: With respect, the MySQL reference manual is published online and is very well indexed by various search engines.

Comment: SO should be the *last* resort for help after you've exhausted other avenues of research, not the first. In this case, a simple Google or Bing search would have located the MySQL documentation, which explains this quite clearly, which indicates to me that you've put little or no effort into finding an answer elsewhere.

Comment: seriously dude , i said im a newbie , not everybody understands what they read on the first sight or even after they read many many times . so that DOESN'T MEAN my FIRST RESORT is asking around helpful pros like you  . you're also a newbie before you become jesus so you don't have to criticize those that are more dumb than you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE TABLE is the sql clause which is required to creating a table.
After that you have to give a table name i.e "Registration Form" .but avoid spaces in between table name
Next what ever you gave those are column name along with their datatype and size.NOT NULL means while inserting data those column can't be  blank.
For more details check the below link
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-create-tables.htm

Comment: after the ) brackets that examples doesn't talk about engine or others that mention .